# Mixing collection hooks modifier operations in hook causes error

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Using Meteor 1.1.0.2 and the `matb33:collection-hooks` package I'm running into an error trying to add a `$set` to the `modifier` object in a `before.update` hook that was called by an `$inc` update.

I have an `after.update` hook on an `Invoices` Collection so when the `Invoices` instance is approved it **increments** a `totalPurchases` counter on a `Products` Collection instance like so:

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
   Invoices.after.update(function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {

      if(modifier.$set && modifier.$set.approved === true) {
          //  Increment product.totalPurchases
          Products.update(doc.productId, {$inc: {totalPurchases: 1}});
      }
   });
}
```

And then a second hook on a `Products` collection that checks if the `totalPurchases` counter has exceeded an inventory maximum and if so, it **sets** a flag on the `Products` instance `modifier` object so when the update occurs on the `Products` instance the `inventoryMaxReached` flag gets updated too:

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
   Products.before.update(function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {

      if(modifier.$inc && modifier.$inc.totalPurchases) {
          //  Check if total purchases is beyond max
          var newTotalPurchases = doc.totalPurchases + $modifier.$inc.totalPurchases;
          if(newTotalPurchases > TOTAL_INVENTORY_MAX)
             modifier.$set.inventoryMaxReached = true;
          }
      }
   });
}
```

The problem is the `modifier.$set.inventoryMaxReached = true` returns an error because I'm adding a `$set` to the `modifier` object. I figured out that if I make the first hook a `$set` instead of an `$inc` then the second hook works fine.  The `modifier` object is only happy when all the operations are the same. So to do that I changed the line in the first hook:

`Products.update(doc.productId, {$inc: {totalPurchases: 1}});`

to:

```
var product = Products.findOne(doc.productId);
Products.update(product.productId, {$set: {totalPurchases: product.totalPurchases + 1}});
```

I thought this solved my issue but I discovered this creates a second problem.  The `totalPurchases` counter will not get incremented correctly if a **ton** of Invoices come in **really fast** because of the way the hooks resolve asynchronously. `product.totalPurchases + 1` will resolve to the same value and not actually increment.  I discovered this when populating my database with initial data in a bunch of `for` loops that executed very quickly.

However if I use an `$inc` like in the first version of the `Invoices` hook, the `totalPurchases` counter updates exactly right.  The problem is that I just can't do a `$set` in any hooks triggered by the `$inc` update, which I need to do.

To try to solve this I actually tried to do an update inside the update hook. I changed:

`modifier.$set.inventoryMaxReached = true;`

to

`Products.update(doc.id, {$set: inventoryMaxReached: true}});`

But that causes what seems like infinite loops in the browser (which I'm not sure why since I have the `if(modifier...)` line to check what kind of update it is.  Regardless if it works, it's hacky to need/try to call and `update` on an instance inside of it's own `update` hook - which is probably why the browser freaks out.  That's what the `modifier` object is for.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?  Is it a Mongo limitation?  Can only one type of operation exist in the `modifier` object?  Or is this a bug?

NOTE: Everything is wrapped in `if(Meteor.isServer)` because if you don't, the increment actually gets called twice, once on the server and once on the client, and it saves a doubly incremented value onto the server.  Also not sure if this is a bug or intended.  I added an issue about this here:

https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks/issues/140

EDIT: I'm thinking this may be a bug in `matb33:collection-hooks`.  As it's perfectly acceptable to call a Mongo update like this mixing operations:

```
Gadgets.update(gadgetId, {$inc: {totalStock: -1}, $set: {inventoryMaxReached: true}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an extra `$` sign: `$modifier.$inc.totalPurchases`. It should read `modifier.$inc.totalPurchases`.

And finally, you need to initialize `modifier.$set` since you only used `$inc`:

```
if(newTotalPurchases > TOTAL_INVENTORY_MAX) {
  if (!modifier.$set) modifier.$set = {};
  modifier.$set.inventoryMaxReached = true;
}
```

Comment: The `$` sign on `$modifier.$inc.totalPurchases` was a typo.  The lack of initialization on `modifier.$set` was the problem.